# Terminal for colorized output on remote linux servers

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I frequently SSH into remote ubuntu servers to observe output.

What I'd like is certain terms (e.g. ERROR) to be colorized, (e.g. in red).

My understanding is that this is typically done by the shell, not the terminal. I do NOT want to change/install anything on remote servers however. I'd like this to be done at the terminal level, so that it would work on my local or remote box.

On Windows, some terminals support this, e.g. Mobaxterm.

[image: mobaxterm]

So I'm looking for something equivalent in Linux land.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Mobaxterm.  I too have had this dilemma.. nothing on Linux seems to be able to do what MobaXTerm can do.. but in this case, I bet someone will know how to pull THIS off.

Comment: Yip be hard to imagine Windows having the edge on something terminal related!

Comment: The closest I can find is Hyper.is.   It looks like maybe one  could write a plugin for this, to highlight terms.  But would rather have something a) out of the box, and b) not Electron based

Comment: Thanks for this @Nik. You might need to write a plugin or to be honest, if it were me and it was making me crazy, I would probably write shell function to accommodate this.  I too am an engineer (mostly c/c++ but "whatever" is fine).

Comment: There's a proof of concept, abandoned work for VTE (the engine behind GNOME Terminal, Tilix, Terminator, Xfce4 Terminal, Guake and many others) at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/7771. The highlighting rules are hardcoded in the patch, you have to change them there and recompile. I don't know how hard it is to apply the patch to current VTE, or perhaps you can use an older version from around the time when the patch was created. No regex support yet, just plain string match. But if you don't mind this amount of inconvenience then the patch is believed to work reliably.

Comment: (con't) I've tried and the patch still applies, just one trivial conflict to manually resolve. I recommend to start from the VTE version and patches shipped by your distro (assuming that it's not older than the patch, i.e. 0.58.0 or newer). After compiling, give it a test run with `./src/app/vte-2.91`. If satisfied, install it system-wide, then restart your choice of VTE-based emulator (quit all its windows at once). Should you mess up this installation, undo it and reinstall your distro packages from a non-VTE-terminal (e.g. xterm or console). Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could [pipe your command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267400/colour-highlighting-output-based-on-regex-in-shell) to `grep` with color:

```
your-command | grep -E --color 'pattern|$'
```

This needs to be done per command though.

---

You [can apply this](https://serverfault.com/a/49887/102584) for the whole shell, by making the `your-command` the shell itself:

```
bash | grep -E --color 'pattern|$'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gauthier, but doing it per command is not going to work. And, making changes to the shell itself is also a no go.  I want this at the terminal level, transparently, to every machine I connect to, without any other changes (like Mobaxterm)

Answer (score 0):

I think the less-standard terminal commands in Linux like [Terminator](https://gnome-terminator.readthedocs.io/en/latest) and [Terminology](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-terminology) do the trick? See [This list](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-terminal-emulators).

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at most (all?) of those, and some are great, but not found the feature I'm looking for.